# Dealing with backslashes in JavaScript, PHP and MSSQL

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server, backslash

Before I get anywhere with this post, let me make this clear, there is absolutely nothing I can change about the string I'm about to show you, it must stay as it is.

I need to find some way of parsing a string without any escaping mechanisms. I have this string: "A2&11203[3\813+!5>di" which is used by this program I'm forced to deal with.

SQL parses that string just fine (backslash and all), but JavaScript and PHP keep using it as an escaping mech and removing the number 8.

What happens in my application is it receives that string and then using JavaScript, redirects to a webpage along with the string, the problem here is the backslash is being removed, which I must have.

I found this code in another stackoverflow post, and it works for what I need, but I need to stop JavaScript (and eventually PHP) from removing the backslash.

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

The string needs to be processed completely raw, i just checked the database and there are several cases with multiple backslashs everywhere along with damn near any character you can find on an english keyboard.

Any ideas as to what I can do about this issue? I'm forced to use JavaScript as the main redirector.

Comment: It's complete nonsense that you can't escape the string. The string isn't even valid as part of a URL, and your web browser *is* escaping the string automatically for you before sending it along, so escaping it *will* happen at least once, so why not other times to keep the data you're carrying valid?

Comment: and where is the string  in your code ?

Comment: The string is the main identity tied to an account, it's unique to each record. The string comes from application that is built into the main program that feeds the data to the HTML page, I'm trying to find out how to carry on that string from the HTML page, and have to redirect to my reporting server. The HTML processor is very skimpy at best, to be honest I'm surprised it can even handle JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no way to properly escape backslashes, we changed to passing 4 other fields that would identify the account and then pulled the accountno within php, no more need to escape anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your flow is something like:

> In PHP, get data from SQL database and output it in JavaScript code. Then, later send it back to PHP for processing.

In which case, you need to do something to the string before passing it to JavaScript.

You can achieve this by calling [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) on the string.

For example, instead of something like:

```
var myvar = "<?php echo $var; ?>";
```

You would have:

```
var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>
```

This means that, no matter what characters are in the string, you will always have that exact string in JavaScript, backslashes and all.

When JavaScript passes it back to PHP, presumably through a form, backslashes are maintained just fine - this is true of any form since the user can type in all the backslashes they want. Just be careful to use the appropriate escaping function for the database type you are using, to ensure any special characters (such as backslashes) are properly escaped.

Comment: No, I don't know what the main program is written in, but it gives me the ability to pull variables and pass them to an HTML document, in that document is where I use JavaScript to then direct the page to my reporting server which runs php scripts. Main Program -> HTML Document (JavaScript redirect) -> Reporting php server. I'm trying to pass the variable from the Main program to the reporting server.